# How to apply one style to control inside template of another style?

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I have style for control:

```
<Style x:Key="base style" TargetType="{x:Type cust:SomeCustomControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type cust:SomeCustomControl}">
                <DataGrid >
                    <!-- some content... -->
                </DataGrid >
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I tries to add another style, which should be absolutely the same as previous but with "Bold" font for first row in DataGrid:

```
<Style x:Key="bold row" TargetType="{x:Type cust:SomeCustomControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource base style}">
??????????????
??????????????
</Style>
```

But I don't understand how can I change some properties in first style without copying entire code of "base style".
I think I should add something like:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RowIndex}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

But my "bold row" style is appliable for cust:SomeCustomControl. So how can I do that inside "bold row" style, without overwritting the whole

```
<Setter Property="Template">
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just add your DataGridCell Style to the inheirted style's resources?

```
<Style x:Key="bold row" TargetType="{x:Type cust:SomeCustomControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource base style}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Style.Triggers>
               <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RowIndex}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

It should use the same template, but the inherited one would apply the trigger to all `DataGridCell` objects

Comment: It was the first thing I've tried, but It does not work unfortunately. I'm not experienced WPF programmer, so I think Style inheritance works in some other way. This trigger is completely ignored.